# Incrementing shift for toString()

Tags: java, tostring

I need to print out a QuadTree. The problem is that I don't know how to implement an incrementing shift in order to be able to visualize the tree structure. 
Currently I just see each level of nodes at a new line. However, it's complicated to use this visualization for working with a tree.

```
         @Override public String toString() {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String NEW_LINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            String SHIFT = System.getProperty("  ");

            if (_children != null) {
                String content = "";
                for (QtreeNode<E> node : _children) {
                    content += node.toString() + ",";
                }
                result.append("{" + SHIFT + NEW_LINE + 
                            content.substring(0, content.length()) + 
                            SHIFT + NEW_LINE + "}");
            } else if (_items != null) {
                String content = "";
                for (E item : _items) {
                    content += item.toString() + " ";
                }
                result.append("[" + content + "]");
            }
            return result.toString();
         }
```

Comment: What do you expect `System.getProperty("  ")` to do? It would be pretty odd to have a property named "  ". It's also odd that you know not to use repeated concatenation when building a string (in that you're using `StringBuilder`) - but you have two loops where you *do* use repeated concatenation...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: In fact, System.getProperty(" ") was my attamept to add a shift. But it's not correct. That's why I posted this topic.

Comment: Well what do you expect "a shift" to be? If you just want a string with two spaces, just use `"  "` (a string literal of two spaces) - there's no need to call `System.getProperty`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide separate toStringWithIndent(int depth) method for your tree Nodes, and call it inside overridden toString(). This method will call same one for each subnode, etc. recursively.

UPD Some example

```
class Node {
    private String name;
    private List<Node> children;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = name;
        for(Node n: children) s += children.toStringWithIndent(1);
        return s;
    }

    private String toStringWithIndent(int depth) {
        // same as toString() but with indent
        String s = indentFor(depth) + name;
        for(Node n: children) s += indentFor(depth) +
                children.toStringWithDepth(depth + 1);
        return s;
    }

    private static String indentFor(int depth) {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(depth);

        while(depth-- > 0) {
            b.append(" ");
        }

        return b.toString();
    }


}
```

Comment: Could you give an example please?

Comment: Do you mean:  return result.toStringWithDepth(depth);
  depth++; In this case do I need to create toStringWithDepth or is it a built-in function?

Comment: Sorry for so many questions, but could you please put the code for indentFor?

Comment: Ok, I've updated. I believe this method can be rewritten better :)